# Who didn't recite Kabbalas Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, history, sources-mekorot

In [this article](http://torahmusings.com/2010/08/women-leading-kabbalat-shabbat-some-thoughts/), R. Michael Broyde writes that:

> Indeed, there have been prominent halachic authorities of the last generation who did not recite Kabbalat Shabbat.

Can anyone provide examples of such prominent authorities? (either from the last generation or earlier achronim)?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible, but I would recommend you try and find his email or a way to contact him.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, his e-mail address is listed at http://www.law.emory.edu/faculty/faculty-profiles/michael-j-broyde.html.

Comment: @msh210 I recommend he email and ask him.

Comment: I have emailed him. Let's not all flood his inbox with messages.

Comment: He responded promptly, but signed it as "A Private Email". So it gave me some ideas where to and not to and to maybe check, but anything I answer below will be sourced _independently_ of the email.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33790

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36016

Comment: The community in Worms didn't say it http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42658&st=&pgnum=87

Answer (score 8):

After a bit of online research, all I could find was the following perplexing statement made by R' Yosef Yozfa Segal in [נוהג כצאן יוסף](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9375&st=%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%AA%20%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA&pgnum=152):

> ובכמה קהלות מנגנים בכלי זמרים ונבלים וכנורים והוא ע״פ מ״ש רז״ל אין השכינה שורה אלא מתוך שמחה כמ״ש בדוד ויהי כנגן המנגן ותהי עליו רוח אלהים עכ״ל ומנהג ק״ק פ״פ שאין מקבלים שבת כל עיקר. רק קדמונים הקימו חברא קדישא שהיו מקבלים שבת. ועודם נוהגים שאחד מבני החברא מתפלל מנח׳ בבה״כ הישנה ואח״כ עומד החזן על הבימה ומקבל שבת. ואח״כ יורד החזן לפני התיבה ומתפלל מנתה לכל הקהל. ובבה״כ החדשה מתפללים מנחה באותו פעם שמתפללין בבה״כ הישנה פעם שנית ואין מקבלים שבת כלל כאשר הוא יסוד מנהגם. וגם בק״ק ווירמייזא אין מקבלין שבת
>
> In some communities, they play instruments, lyres and harps, and this is that which Chazal said: The *sh'china* rests only where there is joy, as it says regarding David: "And it came to pass, when the minstrel played, that the hand of Hashem came upon
> him." The custom of Frankfurt is not to greet the Shabbos at all; but our forebears set up a "*chevra kaddisha*" that would greet Shabbos. They maintain the
> custom that one of the group says *mincha* in the old synagogue and then the *chazzan* goes up to the *bima* and greets the Shabbos. Afterwards, the *chazzan* descends before the lectern and recites *mincha* for the entire community. At the same time, the rest of the
> community says *mincha* in the new synagogue and they do not greet Shabbos at all as is their basic custom. The community of Worms
> also does not greet Shabbos.

Although this whole process he describes is quite strange, it seems that what he means by "*mekabel shabbos*" is at least similar to what we have as *kabbalas shabbos*, in which case it is clear that the communities of Frankfurt and Worms generally did not recite it.

This book was published in 1718, so perhaps not what you might include in "halachic authorities of the last generation", but still nearly a couple hundred years after the custom of *kabbalas shabbos* began.

Comment: Again, like the other response, this seems to be an example of a community that never really accepted Kabbalas Shabbos to begin with. Whereas the question is really for examples of major poskim who did not recite it after its general public acceptance.

Comment: @Curiouser, You mean major poskim who lived in communities that already accepted the practice, but nonetheless refused to recite it? I doubt that such a thing ever existed and I doubt that that's what R' Broyde meant. Probably what we're looking for are poskim who lived among communities who never picked up the practice of *kabbalas shabbos* and voiced their intent not to do so.

Comment: That is exactly what R. Broyde meant, and he supposedly emailed the response to someone already privately (see comments above). To say that there were certain communities (and their poskim) who never accepted the practice is obvious from the other sources already quoted in the other answer. But that is not what R. Broyde's comment was about -- it was about whether there were individuals who decided for themselves not to recite it.

Answer (score 2):

Siddur Avodas Yisroel mentions that you start from Maariv.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21746&st=&pgnum=217

Comment: No, Baer's siddur (in a footnote, quoted in the link you provided, but see the original here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42807&st=&pgnum=197) mentions that earlier siddurim didn't include it. But Siddur Avodas Yisroel does indeed have kabbalas shabbos. The question was who didn't say it *after* it was widely accepted?

Comment: We don't rely on Sidurim unless written by Gedole Torah (En Yitzchak).