# Skipping Kabbalat Shabbat

Tags: halacha, kabbalat-shabbat

Would a person be permitted to make a habit out of skipping Kabbalat Shabbat, and furthermore, would a shul be allowed to make this their official policy? (By "skipping", I mean not saying at all, whether in shul or at home.)

Comment: see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13713/who-didnt-recite-kabbalas-shabbos and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28001/singing-lecha-dodi-before-shabbos

Comment: I know Yeshivot in which they do not make Kabbalat Shabbat betsibbur,  everyone says it alone

Answer (score -1):

Its a custom to receive and sanctify the shabbat as its also a gesture and holy moment of receiving what HaShem gave to us and then sanctifying it with Kiddush. However between the two (kabbalat shabbat and Kiddush) making Kiddush is the most important moment of Friday night. This is further explained by my experience, one day i missed kabbalat shabbat due to a road trip i had to do (stupid me shouldve known better that day) and i told my Rabbi and he told me the least i should do is make Kiddush even if missed Kabbalat Shabbat, further explaining that kiddush is the important aspect more of Friday night service.

Comment: This comment is from experience not a wild guess. I know this site relies on evidence and proof and this is what i gave to answer this question from my experience. For shabbat friday before sunset to saturday nightfall the main aspects of it are Kiddush sanctifying the shabbat with words and wine, and then brief havdalah to close it and seperate it from the weekdays. So if your going to decide to not make kabbalat shabbat atleast light both candles recite the bracha and then make quick kiddush if you dont want to do kabbalat shabbat.

Comment: One should still daven properly from the siddur and include everything.